# Suppress user-visible PHP error messages but not error log messages

Tags: php, error-handling

I'd like for PHP to still send it's minor and fatal errors to the error log but not display it to the user. I thought at first I could use `error_reporting(0);` to suppress all error messages, period, but that's not really ideal. I know I could also put everything inside a try-catch but that's not really ideal either. Is there anything more automatic for regular errors like there are for fatal errors (e.g. `register_shutdown_function()`)?

Speaking of fatal errors, I tried catching them using `register_shutdown_function()` as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error/2146171#2146171). When I did it this way the fatal error was caught but `error_get_last();` is always empty. I also tried making use of `debug_backtrace();` to catch the error message. It *does* contain the info I want about fatal errors but it appears to have the undesired side effect of actually printing that info out to the user, the very situation I am trying to avoid.

Are there any other ways to do what I'm trying to do here and/or ways I can do this (log the error messages to the console but not to the user) using the methods I have described above? Thank you.

Comment: Please see the manual for the settings that exist: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `display_errors=0` and `log_errors=1` in php.ini.

This should be the default for any production server.

Comment: Oh geez, you're right, I'll have to talk to the admin that set up that app server and ask them why php.ini isn't set up that way on production. Thank you!